# Verilog not fully reading the file

Tags: verilog

I am trying to read the input from the file, and it is not reading the file fully. If there are 100 entries, it will only read 99. Here is the file and code. Any help would be appreciated.  How do I know it? It is basically the sum of `hit_count` and `miss_count` should be the total number of input in the file and that is what is missing by 1.

```
module cache_memory_direct_mapped(input clk,
                        input reset,
                        input [3:0]read_addr,
                        output reg hit,
                        output reg miss,
                        output reg [7:0]hit_count,
                        output reg [7:0]miss_count);
reg [1:0]c1[3:0];
 initial 
begin
 hit_count =8'h00; 
 miss_count = 8'h00;
end 
            

always @(posedge clk, posedge reset)                        
 begin
   if(reset)
      begin
       c1[0] <= 2'hx;
       c1[1] <= 2'hx;
       c1[2] <= 2'hx;
       c1[3] <= 2'hx;
      end   
    else  
  begin
   if(read_addr[3:2] == c1[0] || read_addr[3:2] == c1[1] || read_addr[3:2] == c1[2] || read_addr[3:2]     
  == c1[3])
   begin
    hit <= 1;
     hit_count <= hit_count + 1;
     miss <= 0;
   end
  else
  begin
    hit <= 0;
    miss <= 1;
    miss_count <= miss_count + 1;
     if(read_addr[1:0] == 2'b0 )
      c1[0] <= read_addr[3:2];
  else if(read_addr[1:0] == 2'b1 )
      c1[1] <= read_addr[3:2];  
  else if(read_addr[1:0] == 2'b10 )
      c1[2] <= read_addr[3:2];        
  else if(read_addr[1:0] == 2'b11 )
      c1[3] <= read_addr[3:2];  
end
end
end
endmodule

module Tb_direct_mapped;

// Inputs
reg clk;
reg reset;
reg [3:0] read_addr;

// Outputs
wire hit;
wire miss;
wire [7:0]hit_count;
wire [7:0]miss_count;

integer data_file ; // file handler
integer scan_file ; // file handler
reg [4:0]captured_data;

// Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
cache_memory_direct_mapped uut (
    .clk(clk), 
    .reset(reset), 
    .read_addr(read_addr), 
    .hit(hit), 
    .miss(miss),
    .hit_count(hit_count),
    .miss_count(miss_count)
);

initial begin
    // Initialize Inputs
    clk = 0;
    reset = 0;
    data_file = $fopen("data_file.txt", "r");
end

always
#10 clk= ~clk;
always @(posedge clk) begin
scan_file = $fscanf(data_file, "%h\n", captured_data);
 if (!$feof(data_file)) begin
 read_addr <= captured_data;
 //$strobe(hit_count);
 end
 else begin
 //$display("The total hit counts are:");
  $display(hit_count);
  $display(miss_count);
  $finish;
   end
  end        
  endmodule
```

And here is the file:

```
6
9
4
A
8
2
9
5
7
9
7
4
9
7
6
8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for EOF before you read each line of the file:

```
   always @(posedge clk) begin
      if (!$feof(data_file)) begin
         scan_file = $fscanf(data_file, "%h\n", captured_data);
         read_addr <= captured_data;
         //$strobe(hit_count);
      end
      else begin
         //$display("The total hit counts are:");
         $display(hit_count);
         $display(miss_count);
         $finish;
      end
   end
```